# Go to the next line

Tags: c, file, io

I Have file like which will have multiple customer records

```
CUSTOMER ...
details...
details...
CUSTOMER...
details...
details...
details...
CUSTOMER...
.
.
```

I want to split a file  into two and I am counting all the lines in a file and dividing with `2` and checking that line is starting with `CUSTOMER` or not.
 If yes how can I write all the lines before `CUSTOMER` ?
and 
If the line is not starts with `CUSTOMER` how can check the next line whether it is a starts with `CUSTOMER`?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to work with line numbers in a text file is to count newline (`'\n'`) characters from the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

ftell returns the number of bytes you have read in a file.
To go to a particular line you have to count the lines by counting '\n'.
at the 54th '\n' use fgets to read the entire line.